# Counter in Emgu CV 3.2.0

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am using Emgu CV 3.2.0 with c# for pixels detection. I can not find Counter in Emgu CV 3.2.0.

Code is here:

```
Contour<Point> contour1 = cannyGray.FindContours();
```

Where is counter present in Emgu CV 3.2.0? Or has it been replaced?

Answer (score 0):

The count of contours is in the value **Size**. Or in your case contour1.Size.

Doug

Comment: Counter<T> is a class . present in 1.5 version of Emgu. i can not creae a referce to it in 3.2 version of Emgu

Comment: I do not go back as 1.5 as I start in 2.4. But a quick search and I see no such class, Contour yes, Counter no.